# Ansible loop with array

Tags: arrays, json, loops, ansible

How can we create a code as below?

```yaml
- name: TEST1
  set_fact:
    list_a: "{{ list_a + [item.json.SearchResult.resources] }}"
  with_items: 
    - "{{ source_list.results[0] }}"
    - "{{ source_list.results[1] }}"
    - "{{ source_list.results[x] }}"
    ... (unknown how many items in result from API)
  vars:
    list_a: []
```

`source_list.results[x]` comes from an API result. The reason why I need to create an array is that the number of API result is maximum 100. But there are over 500 items.

Comment: This sounds like your going about it the wrong way. Is your end result you want `list_a` to just be a nested list of `source_list.results[0].json.SearchResult.resources` from 0 to x items?

Comment: something like `loop: "{{ source_list | community.general.json_query('results[*].json.SearchResult.resources') }}"`

Answer (score 1):

You are taking this the wrong way. Simply extract the attribute you need from each result using the [`map(attribute=x)` Jinja2 filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map).

Since you did not provide an example data structure, I inferred below  that:

- you called your API with `ansible.builtin.uri` in a loop to get batches of 100 results which are returned as a list in the `SearchResult.ressources` field
- you want in the end a flattened list where all `resources` are at top level

```yaml
- name: Show my list of single attributes
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: "source_list.results
      | map(attribute='json.SearchResult.resources') | flatten"
```

You actually don't need to `set_fact`:

- For a single use, just use the above expression directly in the relevant parameter (e.g. `loop` or a module param....) or eventually declare this in a var at task level.
- If you want to reuse this in different parts of your playbook, just declare a var at play level and expand it anywhere once you have called your API and populated the `source_list` var. In that case, just add a default value to prevent an error if API was not yet called.

Example for the second case above in this pseudo playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    list_a: "{{ source_list.results | d([])
      | map(attribute='json.SearchResult.resources') | flatten }}"

  tasks:
    - name: "This will return an empty list (i.e. [])
        as we did not populate source_list yet"
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: list_a

    - name: Call our API and register source_list
      ansible.builtin.uri:
        uri: https://my.api.com/api/v1/some/endpoint
        # [... more parameters here ... ]
      loop: "{{ my_list_of_ressources }}"
      register: source_list

    - name: "This will now return a populated list
        after calling the API and registering source_list"
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: list_a
```

---

Now, to still give a direct answer to your initial question: you can construct that list iteratively inside a `set_fact` task. **This is definitely not efficient** as it involves a task running inside a loop (both unneeded as demonstrated above) and possibly on multiple hosts in your play. But for learning purpose, here it is:

```yaml
- name: very inefficient way to get the same result as above
  set_fact:
    list_a: "{{ list_a | d([]) + item.SearchResult.resources }}"
  loop: "{{ source_list.results }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading [@Zeitounator's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74673918/9401096), I realized I was taking this the wrong way. I used the idea in the answer (`json query` and `flatten`) and I changed my task to the below which works as expected.

```yaml
- name: Create ID list from API result data
  set_fact:
    list_a: "{{ source_list | json_query('results[*].json.SearchResult.resources[*].id') | flatten }}"
    
- name: API get again with id
  uri:
    url: "{{ request_url }}/{{ item }}"
    ... 
  register: result_data
  with_items:
    - "{{ list_a }}"
```

Comment: We still have no knowledge of your initial data structure which makes this specific answer a bit useless. Please [edit] your question with a correct [mre] to make all this more useful for future users. Thanks.